# Aliasing components

Tags: angular

I need to define a shared component library for a corporate multi-project. Some of these components will be taken from angular-material. Other components will be custom components.

In order to keep things clear, I don't want to have some `<mat-xxx>` components mixed with some `<acme-xxx>` components. I want all components to be `<acme-xxx>` without having to rewrite angular-material components.

Is there a simple way to just alias those components?

I tried to create a simple components which only extends one from angular-material :

```
@Component({
  selector: '[acme-button]',
})
export class ButtonComponent extends MatButton {

}
```

But the compiler complains because I don't give the template in `@Component`.

> Error: No template specified for component ButtonComponent.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best idea would be to create your own components and wrap them around the Angular components, like mirror the @Input and @Output bindings and have the Angular component in the template.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[acme-button]',
  template: `<mat-button></mat-button>'
})
export class ButtonComponent {

}
```